# Overloading issues

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have trouble with function overloading when a function can return either something or undefined only if parameter is also possibly undefined.

For example:

```js
type Point = { x: number; y:number}

function symetry(point : Point) : Point;
function symetry(point : undefined ) : undefined;
function symetry(point : Point | undefined) : Point | undefined {
    if(!point) return undefined;
    return {
        x : -point.x,
        y : -point.y
    }
}



const p1 : Point = symetry({x: 10, y:-4});
const someFunc = (v : number): Point | undefined =>{
    if(v%2 === 0) return undefined;
    return { x:v,y:v}
}

const p2 = symetry(someFunc(0));
const p3 = symetry(someFunc(1));
```

This code does not compiles, with the error (on both `p2 =`  and `p3 =`  invocations:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(point: Point): Point', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Point | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Point'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Point'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(point: undefined): undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Point | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.
      Type 'Point' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

How to fix it ?

Link to [ts repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbygDwFxRICuAtgEYQBOA3FCHseVQL4BQrAZkUgMbAJwkUAM4gSEYJRAAKMIhRQC8ZMACUi2PODVO3PgKGjxkmXJUbuAEwgdkES1HUErNu5Z1de-QSLESpsloaygoAPlAutkj2Tprm4ZFuWKxQqVAIHNIAhGYo6pQSRJRCidHuKWkFwEVCmBVpaTgaALS5wAB0OAA09Q10LW3tIL1sbOysPILCqGAAjMFBGEb+Mpj4ULMADF10eM0ALMyqOpNI0yJw4gBieuhQ0gBuGowUlKpKQQlI1lH26AB8dQaGUeAFIAEzoNAYTb5QrFCLfVxlHQNKo1LC4PAPLr0B6jdinc5gSFLPwmaTCS4QG68aSw44TKYzADMd2WFKp1z00lmqkZrCAA)

Comment: Add another overload : https://tsplay.dev/wE85VW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an overload to a function declaration, the signature of the declaration itself is "ignored" by TypeScript.

```
function symetry(point: Point): Point;
function symetry(point: undefined): undefined;
function symetry(point: Point | undefined): Point | undefined { // no longer in effect
```

As far as TS is concerned, this function can only be called in two ways: with a Point, and returning a point; and with undefined, returning undefined. There is no call signature that allows you to call the function with `Point | undefined`.

If you want to support `Point | undefined`, you have to add it yourself:

```
function symetry(point: Point): Point;
function symetry(point: undefined): undefined;
function symetry(point: Point | undefined): Point | undefined; // good
function symetry(point: Point | undefined): Point | undefined {
```

But you have to make sure this overload is last, as overloads are chosen *in order* and the first overload that matches is used. So don't do this:

```
function symetry(point: Point | undefined): Point | undefined; // bad
function symetry(point: Point): Point;
function symetry(point: undefined): undefined;
function symetry(point: Point | undefined): Point | undefined {
```

or else it'll return `Point | undefined` for all calls:

```
const p1: Point = symetry({ x: 10, y: -4 });
//    ~~ Type 'Point | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Point'.
```

[Playground (good)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbygDwFxRICuAtgEYQBOA3FCAceVVAL7UBQ7AZkUgMbAEcJFADOIEhGCUQACjCIUBeMmABKZYuAce-QcLESpM+VoK8AJhC7IIFjVEvXbFnbwFCR4ydLkLVmqpQAD6OSFY2SHYOKighYREubnqehj4m-kqwWvFOkdGBcaF5LljsUBVQCFxQsgCEmepQlFJElCIlUa7llS3AbSKYPZWV+FAAtI0AdDgANMMjdASTWlMg8yNs7CycfMKiqGAAjIWoGN7GcthjRwAMs0sTACysahx7SAdicJIAYu7oWoANwYpAolBiOWK4WcXXQAD4yiNqsCoABSKAAJnQaAwtzUzVa7QSsLsHBGfQGWFwBCBD3oUCBrA4W3YHy+YGx5yMvlkoh+EH+-Fk+LebP2hwAzICLrz+X93LIjmoxUA)

[Playground (bad)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbygDwFxRICuAtgEYQBOA3FCAceVVAL7UBQ7AZkUgMbAEcJFADOIEhGCUQACjCIUBeMlQAfKLwAmELsghaAlMsXrNSHXqQGOPfoOFiJUmfNMnVx2Kdu8BQkXFJaTkFVQJtXX0jCIso6y1fewCnYNcwpW9VKA1IqwMvFRQc80torHYoKqgELihZAEIM4EMoSikiShE86I5qto6uiv7+-CgAWmaAOhwAGkqRqvoJ6ZB5-rZ2Fk4+YVFUMABGD2KMIJc5bDHDgAZZugJxgBZWQw5dpH2xOEkAMT90PUAG4MUgUSiFUwlHoJdAAPmG1VqwKgAFIoAAmdBoDA3VrtYCdbpxfKJBZVAlErC4AhA+7LIGsDibdgfL5gLFnZwhWSiH4Qf78WR4t6svYHADMgPOPL5fz8skOhlFQA)

Comment: thanks! the key in your answer is `When you add an overload to a function declaration, the signature of the declaration itself is "ignored" by TypeScript`. This is the missing piece. Learned something thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
function symetry(point?: Point | undefined) : Point | undefined {
    if(!point) return undefined;
    return {
        x : -point.x,
        y : -point.y
    }
}
```

the '?' indicates that the parameter is optional.

Therefor even symetry() would work and just return undefined in your case.

I recommend using: `function symetry(point?: Point) : Point | undefined`

Because it defaults to undefined.

Your [ts-repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbygDwFxRICuAtgEYQBOA3FCHseVQL4BQrAZkUgMbAJwkUAM4gSEYJRAAKMIhQB%20AvGTAAlMvmoAPlG4ATCB2QR9WVlEtQEHaQEI5qtVEoSilIQaMn91C1ddgdyFMfysrHCgCAFpHFAA6HAAaMPC6KKhYrXiQVLY2dh5BYVQwAEZNVShdL2MkU3QRMQkpaUx8KDKABiS6PGiAFmY1PyKkEpE4cQAxbh5G6QA3DMYKSg1YLWq9JEM6hrQAPlDwmyWAUgAmdDQMLudA4J29nz9wx48sXDxFpPpF-KFYqla4YUTiSQyYRTCCzXjSe4jVhjCZgADMjXBLShMLhPGkZTUSNYQA)

Comment: what you did here put back the type of p1 to be possibly undefined. This is exactly what I want to avoid, because I want to be able to use p1 as non undefined later in the code